# Object doesn't support property or method 'button' jQuery Autocomplete Combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I basically copied the example file from its official site and add it sequentially:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .ui-autocomplete-loading {
      background: url('js/autocomplete/css/ui-lightness/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') no-repeat right center;
  }
  .ui-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .ui-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .ui-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
  }
</style>
<script src="js/autocomplete/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="js/autocomplete/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="js/combocontrol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

combocontrol.js contains the specific autocomplete combobox just the same as they are in the site.

With this, I am getting the error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'button'` at the line :

```
$("<a />")
                .insertAfter(this.element)
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })...
```

I know I am using different versions. But I have other dependencies, so I have to use it. Also, this should not be a problem as far as I am using them only once not multiply attached!

Comment: What do you mean by "I know I am using different versions"? If you're getting this error, it means the library couldn't be found and loaded. Are you sure the path to the `jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js` library is correct?

Comment: @Ian by different version, I want to mean different version for jquery-ui and jquery core.

Comment: Well those versions shouldn't and don't match up. They're totally different projects on different timelines so the versions have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really we should not forget the basics. They said it all.

Actually my custom js downloaded from jQuery website has only autocomplete widget. and this code is calling `button` method and that is not included in the package. So, I re-downloaded the package with `button` component/widget of jQuery. My ignorance!!